# How can I use jinja2 in python sanic？

Tags: python, web, jinja2, sanic

According to my search.
There are two main views:

1. Install and use the sanic_jinja2
2. Just use the jinja2

But above two methods didn't work to me(Maybe it's my fault).

Could anyone give me some example code?

Comment: Not sure this helps you, but in the March release (in about two weeks) we are releasing this in the officially supported plugin: https://github.com/sanic-org/sanic-ext/pull/39

Answer (score -1):

tool/tmp.py

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
from functools import wraps
from sanic.response import html

# print(__name__) # 当前文件路径
# ★package_path设置templates文件夹的相对路径(对于tmp.py来说)
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader(__name__, package_path='../templates'), enable_async=True)

class Tmp:
    @staticmethod
    def template(template_name):
        def warapper(func):
            @wraps(func)
            async def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
                temp = env.get_template(template_name)
                context = await func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                return html(await temp.render_async(context))
            return inner
        return warapper
```

app.py

```
from sanic import Sanic
from tool.tmp import Tmp


app = Sanic(__name__)
app.static("static", "./static")
# 实例化Tmp
br = Tmp()

@app.route('/dag/<br>/<status>', methods=["GET"])
@br.template('dag.html') # 会自动去templates下查找文件html文件
async def search_branch(request, br, status):
    _branch = br
    _status = status
    _time = request.args.get('time')
    return {'request': request, '_branch': _branch, '_status': _status, "_time": _time}
```

Comment: Jinja2==2.11.3
sanic==20.12.6

Comment: sanic                  22.3.0
Jinja2                 3.1.1